# VS 2012 published web service and click once deployment don't reflect newer version of software

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, .net-4.0

VS 2012 published web service and click once deployment of a Windows forms application based on VB.NET and .Net 4.0 don't serve up the newer version of the software. They keep on serving the previous version. However it works fine with VS 2010. This is on IIS 7/7.5.

Anyone have any idea about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I had to clean and rebuild. VS 2012 added an extra step over 2010.